# Can't make bootable USB to install Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, usb, bootable-media

I cannot for the life of me successfully create a bootable USB drive with the windows 7 installation files on it. I've done it many times before, and never failed so often. Everytime I boot, it just ignores the USB drive and boots off the SSD instead (and yes, I did configure the bios to boot from the USB first)

I can operate from either Windows 7 or (Arch)Linux. I have confirmed that the hardware supports booting from USB, as I have installed OpenSUSE on this same computer from this same USB drive recently (the tool I used is called imageusb, I tried using it for Windows too, but it failed.)

What I have tried is [the manual method](http://bootableusb.net/install-windows-7-usb-drive-easy-way/) utilizing diskpart and command prompt, and the [automated method](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/windows-usb-dvd-download-tool) using Microsoft's official utility for the job. I have tried NTFS, I have tried FAT32, I have tried USB 3 and USB 2 (I have a USB3 sandisk usb flash drive) all fails. I even tried two different ISOs.

I have many times successfully done this with the manual method before, but this time something just isn't falling into place and it's driving me crazy! Naturally, I have also tried the two above mentioned methods several times each, mostly out of desperation.

What should I try next?

Comment: Have you tried using rufus?: https://rufus.akeo.ie/

Comment: -1 SHOW THE ERROR MESSAGE

Comment: @Yass nope, I have not, I will try that.

Comment: You left out some important information, like: In what way does it "Fail"?  How far do you make it?  Does the USB stick boot? Does the Windows setup start at all?

Comment: @barlop there is no error message, it just ignores the USB drive in the boot order and jumps to the next thing (Which would be my SSD)

I added this to the OP

Comment: Rufus did not work any better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was apparently no way for me to trick the BIOS into booting off that USB drive with a windows MBR on it, sadly I don't know the reason, but I suspect it's an issue with the USB drive.

The usb drive was bootable everytime I had tried to boot off it, yet the BIOS wouldn't boot from it, it might be an issue with the BIOS firmware, or something between the firmware and the USB drive.

Either way, since as I said I happened to have linux installed on the system, I booted into my linux installation with the bootable USB drive inserted and updated grub's config.

```
grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

The above would be the usual command to do it for grub2. (Note: You need to have os-prober installed for it to detect the windows installation and the USB drive)

GRUB detected the USB drive properly, and I was able to boot the USB drive through grub and then install windows from there.

In other words, if you are caught in a situation where your computer refuses to install Windows from a USB drive, but for some strange reason allows you to install Linux, you sohuld install any linux distribution that ships with GRUB2 (or a bootloader you are familiar with) and configure it so that you can boot the USB drive from the bootloader rather than directly through the BIOS.

(I recommend using Arch Linux for this job)

However, a good answer to my question would have been to use [YUMI](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/). Since it was given that I could boot into *nix environments from USB but not Windows environments, most likely the USB would have booted into the YUMI bootloader from which I could have then accessed my Windows installation medium on another partition.

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried manually selecting the USB in boot device options? (Different from setting the boot order). On certain HP computers, for example, there is a separate menu to directly select the boot device. Sometimes it can take a couple seconds to be recognized by the bios, similar to how an external HDD needs a few seconds to power up, so this may help.

Comment: well, my specific asus board only supports setting boot device via the UEFI BIOS menus asd far as I can tell from the POST Splash

Comment: No legacy boot mode?

Comment: It has CSM so it suipports both legacy and uefi, it tries uefi first.

Comment: Also I found that in the bios settings there's a boot override option, which is the equivalent to what you meant for selecting the boot drive for a one time override. It did not work, not in UEFI mode and not in Legacy mode.